# postfix: conditionally ignoring certain "User unknown in virtual mailbox table" errors when using a milter

Tags: email, postfix, filter

**NOTE: I have voted to close this question here, and I'm moving it to ServerFault, where there seem to be more questions and answers involving postfix.**

I'm running `postfix version 2.93` under `Debian 8`, and I'm trying to accomplish something unusual.

I have been using a home-grown milter for years which is working well. It runs various tests at each stage of the SMTP dialog: `ehlo`, `mail from`, `rcpt to`, *etc*.

I have configured `postfix` to do its standard checking for "User unknown in virtual mailbox table", and that is also working as it's supposed to.

However ...

In certain rare cases, I'd like to intercept the incoming message during the `rcpt to` stage, ***before*** `postfix` determines "User unknown in virtual mailbox table", and if these messages to unknown recipients come from a small group of certain select ***senders*** and are addressed to a small group of certain select ***recipient names***, I want to process them differently than normal via that milter step.

I have enough information available during the `rcpt to` milter step in order to perform this special processing, but unfortunately, the "User unknown in virtual mailbox table" `postfix` processing already rejects messages to unknown users before the `rcpt to` milter step, and therefore that milter step never gets invoked.

Is there a way to configure `postfix` to only reject messages with "User unknown in virtual mailbox table" if the sender name does not not match certain special patterns?

If so, `postfix` could continue to automatically reject messages to ***most*** unknown users, and it could then pass only those rare, special messages on to the milter for them to be handled during the `rcpt to` step.

I know that I could completely disable the `postfix` unknown recipient tests and then manage this myself during my `rcpt to` milter step for all incoming messages. However, if possible, I'd like to avoid this and somehow tell `postfix` to ***conditionally*** reject most messages to unknown users and to only pass a small subset of those incoming messages from special senders on to the milter processing.

I'm not optimistic about this even being possible under `postfix`, but perhaps one or more of you know of a way that I could accomplish this unusual task.

Thank you very much for any thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I haven't gotten any answer in 7 days, and because I think I might have better luck in the ServerFault forum. I'm moving the question to the ServerFault forum.